# Извлечь первую пару чисел с определенной разницей

Tags: python, python-3.x, список, числа

`s = [71, 72, 75, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 127]`

Есть вот такой список. Нужно получить два рядом стоящих числа, разница между которыми равна пяти или более (только первое совпадение). В примере выше это числа 75 и 95.

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: В чём у вас трудности? Знаете ли вы как попарно список обойти? Знаете ли как найти разницу двух чисел в Питоне? Знаете ли как сравнивать числа в Питоне? Знаете как цикл прекратить по условию? (Или как next() пользоваться с генератором (genexpr))

Answer (score 3):

Однострочник, учитывающий отсутствие требуемой пары:

```
s = [71, 72, 75, 96, 96, 97, 98, 99, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 127]

print (next(((a, b) for a, b in zip(s, s[1:]) if abs(a - b) >= 5), None))
```

[Рабочий пример на repli.it](https://repl.it/JUa2/2)

Answer (score 0):

С помощью while пробегает по индексам списка, когда указанное условие срабатывает - сообщает и прерывает итерацию:

```
s = [71, 72, 75, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 127]
n = 0
while n < len(s) - 1:
    if (s[n+1] - s[n]) >= 5:
        print "#1 = {}, #2 = {}".format(s[n], s[n+1])
        break
    n += 1
```

Как же без решения в одну строчку:

```
[(s[a], s[a+1]) for a in range(len(s)- 1) if (s[a+1]-s[a]) >= 5][0]
```

Если числа не по возрастанию то условие примет вид, альтернатива модулю числа:

```
if (s[n+1] - s[n] if (s[n+1] - s[n]) > 0 else (s[n+1] - s[n])*-1) >= 5:
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from math import fabs
from itertools import zip_longest

s1 = [71, 72, 75, 95, 96, 97, 98, 99, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 127]
s2 = [71, 72, 95, 75, 96, 97, 98, 99, 104, 105, 106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 127]
step = 5

def func(s, i):
    for x in zip_longest(s[:-1], s[1:]):
        if fabs(x[1] - x[0]) >= step:
            return x
    return -1

print(func(s1, step))
print(func(s2, step))
```

Comment: Vladimir Gamalian спасибо

Answer (score 0):

```
def func(s1, *slist):
    for e in slist:
        if e - s1 >= 5:
            return s1, e
        else: s1 = e

print(func(*s))
```